# Mysql string/number order

Tags: mysql

Hello I have an index string field that can contain string or number.
I would like to get the max and the min of this index but I want that a ONLY DIGITS index are order as integer otherwise as string.
For example i want:

```
   ( "1", "5", "10" )       MIN=1 MAX=10 // mind MAX=10 not 5 as string order!
   ( "A", "D", "Z" )        MIN=A MAX=Z
```

I tried this:

```
MAX(IF(CAST(idxfield as UNSIGNED)=0,CAST(idxfield as UNSIGNED),idxfield)) as maxField
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds like you're much better off programming this in a procedural language (like PHP, Perl, Python, Java or C/C++) than SQL.  You'd just write a function "maxvalue()" that would check for "if is_number() {}".  IMHO...

Comment: Even if you got it working it would slow down to the point where it wasn't worth having the index in the first place. Two columns needed, or at a push leading zeros on the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REGEXP` to test if the field is numeric or not.

For example:

```
select '1'  REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'; // returns 1
select 'A'  REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'; // returns 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This ::

```
Select 
idxfield REGEXP '[0-9] as field1,
CASE field1
 WHEN 1 THEN SELECT idxfield from table order by idxfield+0 desc
 WHEN 0 THEN SELECT idxfield from table order by idxfield desc
END as max_value,
CASE field1
 WHEN 1 THEN SELECT idxfield from table order by idxfield+0
 WHEN 0 THEN SELECT idxfield from table order by idxfield
END as min_value
from table
```